# Limit Duration granularity

Tags: go

I've calculated a Duration by subtracting a saved time from the current time:
`time.Now().Sub(oldTime)`

Printing it gives me this:
`1m30.789260489s`

1m30.79s would look better, where I'm using it.  How can I truncate / reduce the granularity of a Duration in Go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> [Package time](https://golang.org/pkg/time/)
>
> ```
> import "time"
> ```
>
> [func (Duration) Round](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Round) 1.9
>
> `func (d Duration) Round(m Duration) Duration`
>
> Round returns the result of rounding d to the nearest multiple of m.
>   The rounding behavior for halfway values is to round away from zero.
>   If the result exceeds the maximum (or minimum) value that can be
>   stored in a Duration, Round returns the maximum (or minimum) duration.
>   If m <= 0, Round returns d unchanged.
>
> [func (Duration) Truncate](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration.Truncate) 1.9
>
> `func (d Duration) Truncate(m Duration) Duration`
>
> Truncate returns the result of rounding d toward zero to a multiple of
>   m. If m <= 0, Truncate returns d unchanged.

---

Use the `Round` or `Truncate` methods on the `time.Duration`.

---

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d, err := time.ParseDuration("1m30.789260489s")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(d)
    fmt.Println(d.Round(10 * time.Millisecond))
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/8b3xAxfSE90

Output:

```
1m30.789260489s
1m30.79s
```